# The list in an alignat environment is pushed to the right

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

How do I get this list centered horizontally?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}


\begin{document}


\noindent {\bf Example} \vskip1.25mm
\noindent \hspace*{1em}
\begin{minipage}{5.75in}
Verify the following evaluations of the sine and cosine functions. 
\begin{alignat*}{6}
{\mathrm{i.})} \ &\sin(120^{\circ}) = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}
\qquad \quad
&{\mathrm{ii.})} \ &\sin(135^{\circ}) = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}
\qquad \quad
&{\mathrm{iii.})} \ &\sin(150^{\circ}) =  \frac{1}{2} \\
{\mathrm{iv.})} \ &\cos(120^{\circ}) = -\frac{1}{2}
\qquad \quad
&{\mathrm{v.})} \ &\cos(135^{\circ}) = -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}
\qquad \quad
&{\mathrm{vi.})} \ &\cos(150^{\circ}) = -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}
\end{alignat*}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: ouch, you should almost  never use `\noindent`, `\bf`, `\vskip`, `\ ` or numbering by hand in a latex document and you have all of these things on one small segment?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the use of the `minipage`, as `align`-and-friends center themselves with respect to the text block:

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{showframe}% Just for this example

\begin{document}

\noindent \textbf{Example}

\noindent
Verify the following evaluations of the sine and cosine functions. 
\begin{alignat*}{6}
  \textrm{i.)~}     & \sin(120^{\circ}) = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \qquad \quad
  & \textrm{ii.)~}  & \sin(135^{\circ}) = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \qquad \quad
  & \textrm{iii.)~} & \sin(150^{\circ}) = \frac{1}{2} \\
  \textrm{iv.)~}    & \cos(120^{\circ}) = -\frac{1}{2} \qquad \quad
  & \textrm{v.)~}   & \cos(135^{\circ}) = -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \qquad \quad
  & \textrm{vi.)~}  & \cos(150^{\circ}) = -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: To be consistent with the file, I need this equation environment within the `minipage` environment.  Are you saying that an `alignat` environment ignores the `minipage` environment?

Comment: @user74973: I don't know what you mean by "to be consistent with the file". If you *have* to use a `minipage`, use it like this: `\par\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth} ... \end{minipage}`

Comment: This example is part of a file - chapter on trigonometry.  I have other statements in `minipage` environments.  I am not familiar with the `\par` command.  Don't I need something like `\par { \noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth} ... \end{minipage} }`?  I have other "things" after this `minipage` environment.

Comment: @user74973: No need for the `{`...`}` around the `minipage`. `\par` ends a paragraph and puts TeX in vertical mode `\noindent` starts a new paragraph which, in your case, is the `minipage` spanning the fill `\linewidth`.

Comment: I put `\par` immediately before the `minipage` environment and got the same display - flush right.

Comment: @user74973: Are you using a `minipage` of width `\linewidth` or `5.75in`?

Comment: The width of the `minipage` environment is 5.75in.  Now that I look at it, the list is centered in the `minipage` environment.

Answer (score 1):

Not really centred, but numbering is automatic with the  tasks`package`and the code is much simpler:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} 
\usepackage{tasks}
\settasks{counter-format=(tsk[a]), label-offset = 0.5em, label-align=right, column-sep=3em, before-skip=1.5ex}

\begin{document}

\noindent \textbf{Example}\bigskip

\noindent
Verify the following evaluations of the sine and cosine functions.
     \begin{tasks}[counter-format=tsk[r].),label-width=2em](3)
            \task $\sin(120^{\circ}) = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$
            \task $ \sin(135^{\circ}) = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$
            \task $ \sin(150^{\circ}) = \frac{1}{2}$
            \task $ \cos(120^{\circ}) = -\frac{1}{2}$
            \task $\cos(135^{\circ}) = -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$
            \task $ \cos(150^{\circ}) = -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} $
            \end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  It is a nice display.  I would like to do this using the `alginat` environment, though.

Comment: From my point of view you shouldn't. It's more complex to realise, the counters are set manually and you'll always have something to adjust. Furthermore, if you have several such environments one after the other, the columns won't be  vertically aligned, which will be ugly.